# forge viewer isolatemulti models in the veiwer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

i am trying to isolate an array of dbid in the viewer that contains multi models. but the problem sometimes isolate model A and sometimes model B is there any way to isolate both models at the same time?

```js
function getExternalIds(model: any): any {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    model.getExternalIdMapping(resolve, reject);
  });
}

//---------------------------------------------
async function isolateAndColorObject(
  viewer: any,
  externalId ? : string[],
  color ? : any
) {
  const externalIds = await getExternalIds(viewer.model);

  let arr: any = [];
  externalId ? .forEach((id) => {
    const dbid = externalIds[id];

    arr.push(dbid);
  });


  for (const model of viewer.getAllModels()) { //viewer.getVisibleModels()
    viewer.isolate(arr, model);
  }


}


//calling the function:
isolateAndColorObject(viewer, [
  "5aa7c220-434e-47ec-966b-7aa35a5327a9-001c988b",
  "5cd83cb7-08c9-4bb2-bf3a-523af6622a4f-000e9567",
  "4845d7d6-c3ba-433c-9418-acbdb1ff7e5f-0011d9e2",
  "7e6d9dcb-b26f-4e71-9eb2-3169d28411da-001e3370",
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

update: I have fixed

```js
function getExternalIds(
  model: Autodesk.Viewing.Model
): Promise<{ [key: string]: number }> {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    model.getExternalIdMapping(resolve, reject);
  });
}

async function isolateAndColorObject(
  viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D,
  externalIds: string[]
) {
  let neededDbId: number[] = [];
  const allModels = viewer.getAllModels();

  if (allModels) {
    for await (const model of allModels) {
      const iExIds = await getExternalIds(model);
      if (iExIds) {
        externalIds.forEach((id: string) => {
          const dbid = iExIds[id];

          neededDbId.push(dbid);
        });
      }
      viewer.isolate(neededDbId, model);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).